# Shopware Event Subscribers and Unknown Arguments

Tags: shopware

I am trying to subscribe to some events in Shopware for a plugin - the most important is "Customer Updates" (or new customers).

I am able to successfully capture the event:

```
// Customer (user) update
$this->subscribeEvent(
'Shopware\Models\Customer\Customer::postUpdate',
'onTriggerCustomer'
);
```

In my "onTriggerCustomer" function:

```
public function onTriggerCustomer(Enlight_Hook_HookArgs $arguments)
{
// Do something
$subject = $arguments->getSubject();
// log this, Logger is a logging function..
$this->Logger($subject);
}
```

I have tried endless attempts to get the contents of $arguments but with no luck, all I really need is the customerID.

Any help in trying to work out what arguments are available would be great?

```
getId();
get('id');
var_export(anything, true);
```

Everything just returns null/nothing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code snippet, you can get the customer id as follow:

```
$this->subscribeEvent(
    'Shopware\Models\Customer\Customer::postUpdate',
    'postUpdateCustomer'
);
....
public function postUpdateCustomer(Enlight_Event_EventArgs $arguments) {
    $customer = $arguments->get('entity');
    $customerId = $customer->getId();
}
```

Comment: Brilliant - thanks, works a treat.

Where do I find that Entity and getId are the options? Was searching GitHub but no joy...

Comment: You can find the documentation about doctrine events in shopware here: https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/models/#model-events.
In the code snippet above I would like to make an additional check if $customer is an instance of \Showpare\Models\Customer\Customer